# How to implement GRNN Algorithm with MNIST Dataset (Python)

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, mnist, mean-square-error

I'm trying to implement [GRNN](http://neupy.com/apidocs/neupy.algorithms.rbfn.grnn.html) with [MNIST handwritten digit dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/oddrationale/mnist-in-csv) using python, 
here is my code, i'm getting Predicted values as NaN

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets, preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from neupy import algorithms
#import sys

print('\nLoading...')
traindata = np.genfromtxt('./MNIST_Dataset_Loader/dataset/mnist_train.csv', skip_header=55000,delimiter=',')
#testdata=np.genfromtxt('./MNIST_Dataset_Loader/dataset/mnist_test.csv',skip_header=9000, delimiter=',')

# Load MNIST Data
print('\nLoading MNIST Data...')
x_train = traindata[:,1:]
y_train = traindata[:,0]

print('\nLoading Testing Data...')
#x_test = testdata[:,1:]
#y_test = testdata[:,0]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(preprocessing.minmax_scale(x_train),preprocessing.minmax_scale(y_train),test_size=0.3)
print("training")
nw = algorithms.GRNN(std=0.1)
nw.train(x_train, y_train)
#nw.fit(x_train, y_train)
print("Predicting")
y_predicted = nw.predict(x_test)
print(y_predicted)
mse = np.mean((y_predicted - y_test) ** 2)
#print(mse)
```

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with NeuPy but isn't fit and train the same thing?
Anyways the problem seems to have something to do with the input data?

Comment: Sorry,i forget to comment it...

Comment: Page at your link states that GRNN is only for regression problem. MNIST is classification problem.

Comment: @viceriel is right, this is the wrong algorithm for your problem. Try using PNN (http://neupy.com/modules/generated/neupy.algorithms.PNN.html#neupy.algorithms.PNN). It has the same idea behind it as GRNN and it works only for classification problems. There is even example in the doc which is very similar to your use case.